# Upload only changes to published website in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Recently I have published my website and uploaded it to GoDaddy server. After that I have made changes in .aspx as well in .aspx.cs files. Then I uploaded that files to server but it throws an error. So anybody is having idea about how to upload only changes to published ASP.NET website.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mentioning what errors you faced would help get an answer. Uploading only changes to an asp.net site should normally work.

Comment: I am not recalling what an error it threw as after getting an error I have republished whole site to GoDaddy server. But still I will appreciate if you can suggest me the best way to upload only changed files to published asp.net website.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do:

1. I keep a copy of the older version locally.
2. Then run a diff tool([folderpatch](http://code.google.com/p/folderpatch/)) to compare it with the new version
3. Generate a patch(zip file)
4. Upload the patch
5. Patch the online version to make it same as my new version

Using a tool ensure that you don't miss any updated files.
Having to upload only one file is a lot faster for uploads.
Using the patch tool on the server, ensures that all files are uploaded to the correct locations.

P.s: I wrote folderpatch to make my life easier. But its free and open source, so feel free to use it where it helps you.